# Stand alone C# compiler

Tags: c#, scripting, compiler-construction, interpreter

We have a software which we use in-house for our day to day work.

It is like a customize CRM (sort of) and Bug Tracking software. We had a small team of 3 developers who had developed this software. Now this team is also working on other assignments.

Recently we are receiving a lot of request for adding functionality from users (who are our employees and all of them are developers working of different projects) in our firm. The original team that created this software does not have enough time to work on enhancing this software. So instead of spending a lot of time in updating as per request and the updating the executable of software for each user, we want to implement a programming/scripting solution that is if possible free and open source.

I was thinking of adding support for a language which is similar to C# to our application. This way the developers will add the features that they require on their own in their spare time if they really need a feature!

Can anyone point me to some such implementation already existing?

I don't know if I am taking the right decision or not regarding C# I would like to get opinion of experts on this also.

TIA

Comment: You want to implement your own interpreter?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to acheive, but if you want to allow other teams in your company to extend the functionality of your product, I'd define a plugin API and allow the product to dynamically load external assemblies.

Answer (score 3):

The framework already comes with a C# compiler you can use at execution time via [`CSharpCodeProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider.aspx).

You might want to look at the [source code to Snippy](http://csharpindepth.com/Downloads.aspx), a small tool I wrote for C# in Depth - that compiles code on the fly, and can act as a reasonably simple introduction to `CSharpCodeProvider`.

Comment: The original software is developed in VB.NET. But now we are using C# exclusively for desktop apps. Can I use the feature of CSharpCodeProvider here?

Comment: @Yogi: Yes - it's just part of the framework - it doesn't matter what language you call it from.

Answer (score 2):

I think I'd look at a scripting solution here; probably [IronPython](http://ironpython.net/) is the easiest to bundle and host, but others are available (including Javascript.NET, IronRuby, IronScheme, Boo, F#, etc)